# Sybase Device creation issue JZ0PA - The query has been cancelled and the response discarded

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to add a new database device using SAP ASE Cockpit Database Creation Wizard.

The script issued behind the wizard is the following:

```
set quoted_identifier on
go
USE master
go
disk init name='COMERCIO', physname='C:\SAP\data\COMERCIO.dat', size='100M', cntrltype=0,vdevno=5, dsync=false, directio=true, skip_alloc= true
go
set quoted_identifier off
go
```

But it only shows me the following error:

> "JZ0PA: The query has been cancelled and the response discarded"

My environment is a Test machine running Windows 7 x64. I have plenty of hard disk space and I have an Administrative Account available. Also, I have "Full Control" privileges in the 'C:\SAP\data\' directory folder.

The server Log does not show any particular remark pointing to this issue, the only thing that records is the following:

> 00:0006:00000:00033:2017/01/23 11:49:52.69 kernel  warning: Ignoring the 'skip_alloc' option for device "Ф ", as it is not applicable to the special devices.

Any ideas?

Comment: It could still be permissions.  The permissions needed are those of the account that ASE is running as, so double check that the user that ASE is running as has full control.  Besides that, I would try running the same commands directly from the isql CLI to see if you get a more meaningful error.

Comment: Michael, actually the user that is attempting the command was "SA", sysadmin.   The problem arises no matter the tool used, isql via command line, isql GUI, TOAD for SAP or SAP ASE Cockpit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. Here is what I did:

From the very beginning I suspected a permissions problem. I suspected the user at the prompt, the SA account and even suspected not to have enough/right file writing permissions at some level.

I had to uninstall the Sybase ASE engine completely and started all over again. This time:

a. First of all, created an user with Local Administrator privileges, only to run Sybase's Services.
b. Created a folder reserved to hold Sybase's Devices. Tested first if it was possible to fully read/write everything in that folder using the account created in step a.
c. Installed Sybase ASE 16.0 SP2. At the step indicated by the installer, choosed the the account created in step a to be responsible of Sybase Services.
d. Done.

Thanks to the people who took the time and effort to read this post.